# adding a Color Picker to the Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) Draw tool

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

how can i add a color picker to the CMV Draw tool like the one in the flex app?[image: Flex color picker]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by modifying the draw template (html) and the js.

Or... yo can use this awsome plugin create by btfou: [Advanced draw widget for cmv](https://github.com/btfou/advanced-draw-widget)

Comment: That link is dead. New link: https://github.com/stevenjh/advanced-draw-widget